# Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request in chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I am facing issue in chrome.
I have one placeholder in aspx page.In that placeholder I am adding :

```
<div><img src="/Images/SocialIcon/facebook48.png" id="facebooklink" alt="F" class="socialmedia" onclick="javascript:FacebookShareClick(\'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=147229178787815&amp;link=http://youtu.be/KadDNFXn6kQ&amp;name=April Sweeps&amp;caption=April Sweeps by H.H.Gregg&amp;description=sdfs dsf&amp;redirect_uri=http://localhost:50314/FacebookResponse.aspx\');"></div>
```

It works perfect in firefox but giving error  **Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.** in Chrome and in safari. Moreover I am finding the html broken. The onclick attribute is not being set.

Can any one help for this?

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping single quotes when it's not needed, which creates a syntax error.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's wrong. Do things properly and it will reduce the number of errors you do.

Comment: I removed escapes. Still the same issue in chrome.

Comment: Then check the documentation of the function you're using, and remove the `javacript:`